# Converting from TableForm to Grid

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, grid-layouts

I wonder if there is an easy way to convert from TableForm to Grid. I have an existing data format that uses the Table function that I’d like to prettify….

Let’s setup a nested table as follows:

```
params = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};  (*example, can be more *);
axes = {"x", "y", "z”}; (*fixed number*) ;
mean = {l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9, l10, l11, l12}; (*example data, maybe more*);
stdev = {m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9, m10, m11, m12};
stat = {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10, n11, n12};
labels = {"params", "axes", "mean\[PlusMinus]stdev", "other stat"};
```

My data format is as follows:

```
expr = MapThread[{#1, {#2, #3}, #4} &, {Flatten@
 Table[axes, {i, 1, Length@params}], mean, stdev, stat}];
mytable = MapThread[{#1, #2} & , {params, Partition[expr, 3]}];
```

Visualizing the table:

```
TableForm[mytable]
```

[image: TableForm output]

I’ve been banging my head on how to format this table using Grid while maintaining the general structure of the table.

Q1. **What is the best way to convert this from TableForm to a Grid.**

Q2. **Is there a better data structure I could use that would allow me to use TableForm or Grid interchangeably?**

Related Question:

[Grid - sizing and spacing problems with spanning cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13349/grid-sizing-and-spacing-problems-with-spanning-cells)

Comment: So your question is how to get the same result with `Grid`? Are `Columns/Rows` allowed?

Comment: [rows alignment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25957/5478) - related topic

Comment: @Kuba: yes. I’d like to figure out how to get similar result with Grid. Sure use Columns/Rows inside the grid if you’d like…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the shortest one but I like to use it when I'm making complicated grid layouts.

Basically it is about creating empty grid and fill it with the content you want step by step.

```
m = ConstantArray["", {12, 4}];
m[[2 ;; ;; 3, 1]] = params; 
m[[;; , 2]] = Join @@ ConstantArray[axes, 4];
m[[;; , 3]] = Column /@ Transpose[{mean, stdev}];
m[[;; , 4]] = stat;
m = Join[{labels}, m];


Grid[m, Dividers -> {Thread[{1, 2, -1} -> 1], Thread[{1, 2, -1} -> 1]},
        ItemStyle -> {{Directive[Bold, 18]}, {Directive[Bold, 18]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. This is a good starting point. Any hints on best practice for formatting the above grid? Say drawing grid lines, applying formatting to labels and aligning various columns and numbers?

Comment: @Pam I've made an edit. Also take a look at [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38698/assigning-an-equation-as-a-variable/38706#38706)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it. I have a couple more questions. Specifically dealing with very long text and formatting column sizes. For instance, if I change params to  params = {"Some Very Very Very Long Text", "B", "C", "D”}; and have to size the columns by adding ItemSize -> {{18, 5, 10, 5}, {}} it seems to produce some strange behavior in the columns. Specifically the spacing between x,y and z changes… how do I get around this?

Answer (score 4):

The following method is not fast, but very flexible if you have complicated nested `Grid` :

```
mytable //
   ReplacePart[#, x : {_, _, _, 2} :> Column[ Extract[#, x], Dividers -> None]] & //
   ReplacePart[#, x : {_, 2} :> Grid[ Extract[#, x], Dividers -> None]] & // 
 Grid [#, Dividers -> None, ItemSize -> {{0, 7}, 7}] &
```

[image]